# Jetpack Compose - change variables inside Compsable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to know how I can change variables INSIDE a Composable via a method.
Of course i can do something like:

```
 var test: String by remember { mutableStateOf("hello") }
```

and can change it like I want to, like (although it is a stupid example)

```
          [stuff...].pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(...)
                { change, dragAmount ->
                    test=dragamount.toString()
                }
            }
```

but how would i change the variable with some complicated method e.g.

```
  [stuff...].pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(...)
            { change, dragAmount ->
                changeText(dragAmount)
            }
        }
```

I can only use methods outside of the composable to assign it to the value, aka

```
test=getMyNewTest(dragAmount)
```

But how can i change my 'fields' inside a composable, so that i can modify 'test' directly in my method?

Comment: What does it mean in my method?

Comment: Like i would access fields in classes, if I'd view my composable as a  class, I want it to have methods to alter its mutable states

Answer (score 1):

If the method can see the a mutable variable (i.e. share a lexical scope) it can change it. For `changeText` to be able to  change `test`, it must either have `test` in scope or receive a mutable reference to `test` as a parameter. Compose doesn't change this.

Any answer to this question outside of compose (e.g. class scopes, modules scopes, global scopes, closure capture, reference passing, etc.) works in compose as well.

For example, you could define the function as local to the composable function as,

```
@Composable
fun Example() {
  var test by remember { mutableStateOf("hello") }

  fun changeText(amount: Float) {
     test = amount.toString()
  }
   ...
  
  [stuff...].pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(...)
            { change, dragAmount ->
                changeText(dragAmount)
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I figured it could be a trivial question, but can you give me an example as I do not understand yet? I defined a composable method with a mutable state and want to define my 'changeText-Method' within its scope.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was to place the method outside the scope by misplacing it by a brace, thanks!